# How does one get the ASCII number of a given char?

Tags: c#, string

I need the ASCII value of each character in a string.  I know how to convert the string into a byte array so I can loop through each character, but how do I get the ASCII value of each byte?

In the code below...

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
byte[] chars = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
for (int x = 0; x < chars.Length; x++)
{
    Console.Write(chars[x].ToString() + " ");
}
```

I can definitely get string representations of each character's ASCII value.  I could then add the Convert function to it and be home free...

```
Console.Write(Convert.ToInt32(chars[x].ToString()));
```

But this seems needlessly wordy - there must be a function that would take each byte and give me the ASCII code number.  What is it?

Comment: Or you could even do `(int)s[x]`. A string is an array of chars.

Comment: Keep in mind that a single character in UTF-8 may take more than one byte to store. As long as you use only characters from the [Ascii Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you should be fine, but once you get a non-English character in your string you will start seeing stranger characters appearing in your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Console.Write("{0} ", (int)chars[x]);
```

or as stated by others in the community:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
for (int x = 0; x < s.Length; x++)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", (int)s[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select may be an easy way to write what you want to do:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
byte[] chars = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
int[] ascii = chars.Select(ch => (int)ch).ToArray();
```

and if you want to write the `int[]` values somewhere you could use `String.Join` like this:

```
string asciiString = String.Join(ascii, ", ");
```